# Java sample code for checking emails in a mailbox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a basic backend Java springboot job that will do the following:

1. Run every x minutes
2. Pull all unread emails from a specific outlook mailbox
3. Perform some task with the data in the emails

I've been looking around for some sample Java code to get me through step 2, but I haven't found anything too useful. I will keep looking, but does anyone have anything handy? Again, this is a backend job that doesn't have any UI or login for authentication.

Thanks

Comment: First, you have to know how to access your email server. Is it POP3, IMAP ?

Comment: So this is on our corporate network, and based on instructions I found online to check the type, I'm seeing "Microsoft Exchange". Was expecting to see POP/IMAP, unless I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

For Point #2 - Pull all unread emails from a specific outlook mailbox, You can use Microsoft Exchange service APIs - [ews java api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide).